# Shooting of Philando Castile | Jury Verdict

Tags: jury

I am quite amazed by the verdict from the jury on Philando Castile's case where the cop was acquitted of any charges despite the graphic [video evidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85Y_yOm9IhA).

**Question:** Are jury selected from the same community the crime is committed (in random) or they are based on educational merit. With the evidence presented it was more statistically probable that either jury would not reach a conclusion or will verdict will lead to conviction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Specifically in Minnesota](http://www.mncourts.gov/Jurors.aspx),

> the Minnesota Judicial Branch obtains names from a list of licensed
>   drivers, state identification card holders, and registered voters
>   residing in your county and compiles that information into a source
>   list. The names of deceased persons, provided by the Department of
>   Health, are removed from the source list. From that list, individuals
>   are randomly selected by computer.

Insofar as Minneapolis is in Hennepin County, residents of Minneapolis would not be called as jurors, but any resident of Ramsey County could be.

Comment: This is quite surprising that a randomly selected sample out of population would yield such ill-logical verdict. Some cases have strong evidence as well as emotional affinity that could lead to majority of people believing in one way or other, this is such case where majority neutral parties would either wont reach a conclusion or would conclude a conviction but what is quite un-understandable is how could jury "unanimously" evicted the defendant despite random selection.

Comment: Also why residents of Minneapolis would not be called as jurors?

Comment: Minneapolis is in another county. You can't acquit or convict by majority vote, at least with the current US Constitution and the way it is interpreted by the courts. Any mere majority necessarily returns to deliberation until unanimity results, or the jury really cannot reach a verdict, and they have to do the trial over.

Comment: @gfdsal did you sit through the trial, see all the evidence (not just the salacious evidence the media chooses to show), hear both lawyers arguments and the judges directions? If not, you have no way of telling if the verdict was illogical or not.

Comment: @DaleM good point, but the video evidence I added in the link shows ALL there is to the unbiased recordings. I dont have any reason to believe that any levels of persuasion would result in unanimously acquittal after seeing that video. On the contrary Mohamad Noor another cop got third degree on a similar situation but with added detail of poor visibility (night time). The thing I am trying to grasp is more of a psychology thing that related to the case i.e  how much a "skilled lawyer" can persuade a public despite unbiased video evidence.

Comment: @gfdsal from the Wikipedia article on the matter the verdict turned on the specific wording of the law, that is, manslaughter requires more than killing someone.

Comment: @DaleM I didnt understand what did you mean by "manslaughter requires more then killing someone" Could you please clarify on this point.

Comment: @gfdsal manslaughter is defined by law and all the elements of the crime need to be proved. One of the elements is killing someone but just killing someone is not enough for manslaughter. I suggest you ask a question about what manslaughter is.

Answer (score 1):

The jury is selected (semi-randomly*) from members of "the state and district where the crime shall have been committed", per the Sixth Admendment; as a practical matter, they are pulled from the prosecuting county**.

*The initial selection is done at random; however, lawyers from both sides will eliminate prospective jurors , in a process known as "voir dire" or "jury selection", to eliminate biased jurors.

**In certain cases, the defense can move to change the location that the trial is held and/or the jury is selected from, if they have evidence that the jury pool has been "tainted" against them.

Comment: Allright, but somehow the thing I dont understand that desipte this so-called "unbias random selection" in place how could jury "unanimously" acquit the charges despite visual evidence.

Comment: @gfdsal the visual evidence does not by itself establish all the elements of the crime of manslaughter.